# Were Kurds Fascist?

Tags: republican-party, kurdistan

Trump recently implied as much. I came across this,

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/1943_Barzani_revolt

Kurds rebelling against the Allies. Were kurds Fascist?

Comment: What do you mean fascist? I think you mean Kurds are racist right?

Answer (score 5):

The [1943 Barzani revolt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1943_Barzani_revolt) was one of several attempts by Kurdish groups to gain self-determination and their own state. Its roots were in the [1931 revolt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahmed_Barzani_revolt) and it was triggered by economic issues in Iraq, not the war that was raging in much of the world:

> The impetus for Barzani's return was strictly economic, not nationalist nor caused by a desire to counter any anti-British sentiment in Kurdistan…

You could try to find fault with the British for not setting up a Kurdish state, but they were very much occupied with WWII, and the issue of the Kurds was not an obvious priority for them.

The Soviets gave some support to the Kurdish [Republic of Mahabad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Republic_of_Mahabad) that was set up on Iranian territory in early 1946, but their motivations in doing so were almost certainly to exploit the Kurdish question to make life more difficult for Western-aligned governments.

To summarise, this rebellion had nothing to do with the World War, and claiming the Kurds supported the Axis because of it is a misunderstanding of history.

If they had supported the Axis, the Kurdish troops in the [Iraq Levies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iraq_Levies) would presumably not have served in the [Parachute Company](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/54956/how-were-kurds-involved-or-not-in-the-invasion-of-normandy) with the Royal Marine Commandos in Albania and Greece.